# if I have more than three cards, how can i create a new row for the 4th card in reactstrap or bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap, card

i am newbie in javascript and react. I need a way to automatically arrange the cards in new rows. Something like three cards per row, and if I have more than three, create a new row for the 4th card. and i find an answer but i couldn't convert that way to my project.
I am self-taught and it is my first project practice.

My code:

```
{
  this.props.products.map((product) => (
    <Row>
      <CardGroup>
        <Card>
          <CardImg
            top
            width="100%"
            src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/images/1.jpg`}
            alt="Card image cap"
          />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle tag="h5">{product.productName}</CardTitle>
            <CardSubtitle tag="h6" className="mb-4 text-muted">
              author
            </CardSubtitle>
            <CardText>casdadasdx</CardText>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </CardGroup>
    </Row>
  ));
}
```

Answer: You could create an array with groups of 3 cards and then iterate over them:
Answer code:

```
const arr = var x = arr.reduce((item, key, index) => (index % 3 == 0 ? item.push([key]) : item[item.length-1].push(key)) && item, []);

const Items = ({items}) => (
  <>
    <container>
      {arr.map(group => (
        <row>
          <CardGroup>
            {group.map(card => (
              <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{item.NOME}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">{item.CATEGORIA}</Card.Subtitle>
                  <Card.Text>{item.DESCRICAO}</Card.Text>
                  <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
                  <Card.Link href="#">Another Link</Card.Link>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            ))}
          </CardGroup>
        </row>
      ))}
    </container>
  </>
);
```

Comment: Hey, it's not logic issues - you should handle it in css - especially in flex.

Comment: CSS Trucks had a great article about [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This has everything you need to know for your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

[image: Screenshot]

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Row, Col, Card, CardHeader, CardBody } from "reactstrap";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Row>
        {Array.from(Array(7)).map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Col md={4} lg={4} sm={4} xs={12} key={index}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader>Header {index + 1}</CardHeader>

                <CardBody>Body {index + 1}</CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          );
        })}
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the full working sample https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-thunder-drchc?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: thanks, it is ok.  how can i get card headers, title, etc. from my db.json file?

Comment: @codingmonster I dont get what you mean. could you please explain more?

Comment: i have an api on the localhost:3000 like this:{
    "id": 1,
    "categoryId": 2,
    "productName": "Chai",
    "quantityPerUnit": "48 - 6 oz jars",
    "unitPrice": "24",
    "unitsInStock": 53
  },  i coded  getProducts function asynchronously on the app.js component;  getProducts = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/products")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ products: data }));
  };  but when i mentioned in cardBody cardTitle , etc. i couldn't get data from my api

Comment: @codingmonster I think this is different issue as your initial question. You can open new question based on your comment above. Please accept my answer if its answer this question.

Comment: @codingmonster please open new question and post the link here. I'll try to help.